# how to use load balancer route traffic to REST based stateless services which not spread on all nodes of a given node type

Tags: azure-service-fabric

say, I have a service fabric cluster with one node type which has 5 nodes, and deployed two stateless services on those 5 nodes, but I would deploy service_1 on 3 nodes and service_2 on 2 other nodes.

I understand that a node type is actually a VMSS and azure will create a load balancer on top of that VMSS. It works perfectly on REST stateless service which spread to all of nodes of certain node type.

But in my case, the service deployed on part of nodes, can I still leverage the load balancer to route to instances of two separate services?

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options:

- Use the built in HTTP gateway service from Service Fabric. Unfortunately, I haven't found any documentation about this yet, so I don't know about the advantages and disadvantages of this solution. See [this comment](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/5#issuecomment-220528810) in the service-fabric-issues project for some details.
- Implement your own stateless gateway service which has an InstanceCount of -1 (which means it gets placed on every node). This service will act like an internal load balancer and route every request to the correct service. See [weidazhao's](https://github.com/weidazhao/Hosting) (a Microsoft employee - this project might become part of the SDK) or [our project](https://github.com/c3-ls/ServiceFabric-Http) for existing gateway projects.
- Keep using one load balancer which points to the whole scale set and use probe methods to let the load balancer disable nodes on which the service is not running. However, in case of placement changes, this results in failing requests until the load balancer figures it out.
- Create separate node types (VM Scale Sets) for every service and create a separate load balancer for each node type. However, this results in management overhead and might not be ideal in terms of resource usage.

There is an open [feature suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/293901-service-fabric/suggestions/11028141-bind-load-balancer-to-services-for-hosting-asp-ne) for this topic on the Azure UserVoice site - your votes would be welcome.

Comment: Thanks a lot for great suggestions.

Comment: I haven't been able to configure option 1 myself, but option 2 works flawless if you indeed set the InstanceCount to -1 for the GatewayService